# How to authorize as a Venue in Foursqaure Oauth dialog?

Tags: oauth, foursquare, reply, checkin

If you see the Oauth dialog window below, you can see the defaults are usually "Authorize as a User" or "Authorize as a Page". How to force "Authorize as  Venue"? I need this in order to use the Special API for venues.

And also can anybody show me some light if there is a chance to reply to a checkin for venue. I am unable to find the API endpoint for it.

[image]

Any help would be great?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot force the OAuth dialog default to authorizing as a page.

If you use our [Apps Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/apps), you can reply to check-ins and send messages to Foursquare users in the check-in detail screen.